# How to write this nginx rewrite rule

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, nginx-location

I have a nginx rewrite rule like this

```
        location ~* /question\-(.*)\.html$ {

                rewrite  "^/question-([0-9]+).html$" "/question/$1.html";
                rewrite  "^/question-([0-9]+).html$"  /question.php?id=$1&lm=&pn= break;

         }
```

This rule mean is:
if URI is /question-123456.html so rewrite to /question/123456.html
/question/123456.html is static file, and via question.php to create.

So when I visit http://example.com/question-123456.html HTTP rewrite to http://example.com/question/123456.html if not exist, I want to execute next rewrite `rewrite  "^/question-([0-9]+).html$"  /question.php?id=$1&lm=&pn= break;`

Other than return 404 to user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would write it this way:

```
location ~ /question-(.*)\.html$ {
    try_files /question/$1.html /question.php?id=$1;
}
```